# questions about a term and a notation from a linear algebra exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following exercise:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Qqp.png)

1. when they write $V^T_1$, do they mean $(V^T)_1$ - which is the first column of $V^T$, or $(V_1)^T$, which is a row?
2. when they write "outer product expansion" - what do they mean? they did not explain it in the book, and I could not find anything about the expansion in google - only regular, vector outer product.

Comment: 2. Maybe  the outer product in the exterior algebra? A familiar example is the cross product of two vectors in geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. They write $\mathbf{v}_1^T$, not $V_1^T$. The former is the transpose of the first column of $V$.
2. The outer product of two $n$-dimensional column vectors $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ is $\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T$. Note that this is an $n \times n$ matrix. (Contrast it with the inner product, $\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{v}$, which is a scalar.) They don't mean anything more than the explicit expansion they've already written. You can ignore the words "outer product" for the purposes of actually doing the exercise.

Comment: how would you write the first column of $V^T$?

Comment: The subscript notation is vague no matter what. They clearly mean $V = [\mathbf{v}_1 \cdots \mathbf{v}_n]$, so $\mathbf{v}_i$ is the $i$th column, even though they haven't explicitly said so. From an abstract perspective this makes the most sense: the linear transformation corresponding to the matrix $V$ sends $\mathbf{e}_i$ to $\mathbf{v}_i$. The clearest way to reference the first column of $V^T$ is simply to say, "Let $U = V^T = [\mathbf{u}_1 \cdots \mathbf{u}_m]$."